# Triangle and Median related question

Tags: geometry, triangles, congruences-geometry

> Let BD be a median in  triangle ABC. The points E and F divide the
> median BD in three equal parts, such that BE = EF = FD. If AB = 1 and
> AF = AD, find the length of the line segment CE.

I have tried few standard tools like using mass point geometry as well as Stewart's theorem but had no success. I do get a feel that I am not able to see something very obvious in this geometrical construct. Help is appreciated.

Comment: have you drawn a diagram?

Comment: Even if you did not notice the easy solution through similarity of triangles, I do not agree that you applied Stewart's Theorem and had no success. You probably made a mistake. Even though it will be longer working, you should have gotten the answer.

Comment: Stewart's Theorem gave me a relationship which looked seemingly complicated so I did not pursue it further. However I now realise the solution provided by Cosmos is so so blindingly obvious that I feel like banging my head on the wall.  Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Indeed there is something really simple in this construct : given the lengths and angles, it can be shown that

$$\triangle AFB \cong \triangle CDE$$

by $SAS$ congruence. Using $\triangle AFD$ is isosceles, gives $\angle AFB=\angle CDE$.

Hence $CE=AB$ follows.

Comment: Many thanks. I am up voting your answer and simply down voting myself for not doing simple angle chasing instead wasting my time with complicated tools like MPG.